# Running macro using defined variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with a simple script and am definitely overlooking something small.

```
Dim VEXR as boolean
Dim VE0X as boolean
    If [G8]="A10" or [G8]="B03" or [G8]="B10" or [G8]="B12" or [G8]="B14" then VEXR=true else VE0X=true
    If VEXR=true then [A67]="VEXR"
    If VE0X=true then [A67]="VE0X"
```

For some reason, when "A10" (or any other specified value above) is selected (from a dropdown menu), it returns that VE0X is true, which is incorrect.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what kind of drop down, data validation, activex, form control?

Comment: It's a dropdown menu that pulled from a table on a different sheet (data validation).  I didn't use VBA for that function.

Comment: I assume G8 is the cell that is linked or is the drop down.  You need to fully qualify the object >> Sheet.range("G8").Value.   [G8] means nothing to VBA

Comment: That did it!  Thank you, @Sorceri!

Comment: When you use [Shortcut Range](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html) and want the value. It should be `[G8].Value` to test it just do `Debug.Print [G8].Value`

Comment: For future reference `Select Case` may be eaiser to build / debug / maintain` than `IF ... Or ... Or ... Or ... Or ... Or ... `

Comment: That was really good advice, thanks @ScottHoltzman.  I hadn't seen that function before.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @danieltakeshi, I hadn't seen that before either!